Make custom right click context button only appear in vertex select mode
I'm trying to create an addon that lets you merge at center all the vertices that are in proximity of your cursor (the tool will create a sort of circle selection that moves along your cursor, and all the vertices in the circle will be affected)
This is what I have so far
bl_info = {
    "name" : "Sew Vertices",
    "author" : "bad_lvck",
    "version" : (0, 0, 1),
    "blender" : (4, 10, 0),
    "category" : "Edit mode",
}

import bpy

class SewVerticesOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "mesh.sew_vertices"
    bl_label = "Sew Vertices"
    bl_description = "Merge at center all the vertices inside a circle selection"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.draw_radius = 1
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        obj = context.object
        return (
            obj and obj.mode == 'EDIT' and 
            obj.type == 'MESH' and 
            context.tool_settings.mesh_select_mode[0]
        )
    
    def execute(self, context):
        #Placeholder

def draw_context_menu(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    layout.operator(SewVerticesOperator.bl_idname)
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SewVerticesOperator)
    for f in bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_context_menu._dyn_ui_initialize():
        if f.__name__ == draw_context_menu.__name__:
            bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_context_menu.remove(f)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_context_menu.append(draw_context_menu)
    
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SewVerticesOperator)
    for f in bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_context_menu._dyn_ui_initialize():
        if f.__name__ == draw_context_menu.__name__:
            bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh_context_menu.remove(f)
            return

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

As you can see I'm checking that the mesh select mode type in the poll function of my operator class is vertex select, but having edge select or face select doesn't make the button disappear from the right click context menu, it simply makes it unclickable. I know it's possible to make it completely disappear because the right click context menu has different options based on which mesh select option you're using.
How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.
